# Prove that the commutator subgroups of $G$ are normal in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a group, show that all $G^{(k)}$ are normal subgroups of $G.$

Here, $G^{(1)}$ denotes the subgroup generated by $aba^{-1}b^{-1} = [a,b]$ for every $a,b \in G.$

For every $a \in G,$ one has $$g [a,b] g^{-1} = [gag^{-1},gbg^{-1}] \in G^{(1)}$$

Now observe that 
$$gaba^{-1}b^{-1}g^{-1} = gag^{-1}gbg^{-1}ga^{-1}g^{-1}gb^{-1}g^{-1} = (gag^{-1})(gbg^{-1})(gag^{-1})^{-1}(gbg^{-1})^{-1}= [gag^{-1},gbg^{-1}]$$

Hence $G^{(1)}  \triangleleft G.$ Let $\varphi \in \operatorname{Aut}(G).$ Then $$\varphi(aba^{-1}b^{-1}) = \varphi(a) \varphi(b) \varphi(a)^{-1} \varphi(b)^{-1} \in [a,b]$$

Since $\varphi$ is a group automorphism if the generators of $[a,b]$ are mapped to itself, it follows that $\varphi([a,b])=[a,b].$ Thus the commutator subgroup is a characteristic subgroup.

Comment: The claim $gag^{-1}gbg^{-1}ga^{-1}g^{-1}gb^{-1}g^{-1} = (gag^{-1})(gbg^{-1})$ is false, and it looks like you're assuming that $\phi$ is an inner automorphism.

Comment: @CuddlyCuttlefish fixed, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Careful! I am not entirely sure what you're writing, but recall that normality is **not** transitive, so that an argument of the form $K\lhd H\lhd G\implies K\lhd G$ is incorrect. What you can show is that the commutator subgroup of a group $G$ is a characteristic subgroup: if $\psi: G\to G$ is an automorphism, $\psi(G')=G'$, for $\psi[g,h]=[\psi g,\psi h]$. Since characteristicness **is** transitive, it follows from $G' \,{\rm char}\, G$ that $G^{(k)}\,{\rm char}\, G$ for every $k$. Since inner automorphisms are in particular automorphisms, it follows every derived subgroup is in particular normal.